# Can't use string as a value for _id in Elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Heyo,
We have a document object with property `Id` (that we know auto maps to the `_id` field) and we can get it to work as an `int` and a `System.Guid`.

However when we change it to a string, which would better fit our use case, we get the following exception when trying to index:

`mapper_parsing_exception Reason: failed to parse [id] CausedBy: Type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: For input string: "R700"`

Not really sure what to try here. We want to have a string `_id` and according to online resources we should be able to, however we get this exception.
Any help much appreciated!

**EDIT**: we are inferring the Id from a property named Id on the POCO, I should have clarified.
Example:

```
public class MyDocument {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did you already create the index with an int or a guid as the Id?  If so, you may need to recreate the index.

Comment: Ahhah okay I'll try that

Comment: That worked! Thank you

Comment: Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have already created the index with an int or a guid as the Id field, you will need to recreate the index with the new POCO that has the string as the Id field before you can store that type in the index.

Answer (score 1):

Another option will be to create proper mappings for all your fields so auto-inference will be disabled.